# Filter element node using LINQ in XML

Tags: c#, linq

I am trying to get the value of tag `<ActivityDTTM>26/11/2015 05:25:31</ActivityDTTM>` using LINQ

```
 //I am getting the desire nodes here, but how can I extract the value
 var res = XDocument.Load(fileName)
  .Descendants("CNSDocument").Elements()
  .Select(xe => xe.Name.LocalName);
    }
```

> XML

```
<packet>
<SequenceID></SequenceID>
<CContextInfo>
    <PatientOID>1000000035339</PatientOID>
    <ClinicalDocumentCode>PatientVisit</ClinicalDocumentCode>
    <SessionKey>ecfiosudc1wzeqtwc5k3cp3a#635841108518316124</SessionKey>
    <TransactionCode>TRGMDMT02</TransactionCode>
    <Identifier>CC_CONT</Identifier>
    <ISTransactional>false</ISTransactional>
    <ISPersist>false</ISPersist>
    <UserID>600000190159</UserID>
    <OrganisationID>600000161694</OrganisationID>
    <MessageDateTime>26/11/2015 05:25:35</MessageTime>
    <RecevingDeviceCode>RY7</RecevingDeviceCode>
    <IsReplayed>false</IsReplayed>
    <TrustIdentifier>RY7</TrustIdentifier>
    <SendingOrgID>RY7</SendingOrgID>
    <SendingSystem>CSCLRC</SendingSystem>
    <ReceivingSystem>KIOSK</ReceivingSystem>
    <iXmlVersion>1.0</iXmlVersion>
    <AppStackVersion>2.666.0.0</AppStackVersion>
    <MessageType>MDM_T02</MessageType>
    <ProfileOID>600000000003</ProfileOID>
</CContextInfo>
<TRGMDMT02>
    <CNSDocuments>
        <CNSDocument>
            <EventType>DOC-C</EventType>
            <DocType>CC_LETMULTICNTPAT</DocType>
            <ActivityDTTM>26/11/2015 05:25:31</ActivityDTTM>
            <CreatedDTTM>26/11/2015 05:24:58</CreatedDTTM>
            <OriginatorCPOID>600000190159</OriginatorCPOID>
            <DocumentUUID>8270DAC1-6230-4254-892E-F44954D3DACC</DocumentUUID>
            <DocumentFileName>Multiple conatct letter- Pat - sq MrKOHLI,virat 20151126052458</DocumentFileName>
            <CompletionStatus>CC_CLN_FINALIZE</CompletionStatus>
            <DocumentName>Multiple conatct letter- Pat - sq MrKOHLI,virat 20151126052458</DocumentName>
            <DocumentTemplateName>Multiple conatct letter- Pat - sq</DocumentTemplateName>
            <DocumentStatus>F</DocumentStatus>
            <DocumentOID>900000023052</DocumentOID>
            <PatientOID>1000000035339</PatientOID>
            <EncType />
            <EncounterOID>1000000037823</EncounterOID>
            <DocumentContentType>3</DocumentContentType>
            <DocumentFormatType>CC_HTML</DocumentFormatType>
            <PLCCommunicationProfileOIDs />
            <IsMDMCheck>1</IsMDMCheck>
        </CNSDocument>
        <HeaderDetails>
            <SendingApplication>CSCLRC</SendingApplication>
            <ProcessID>LZO_R2 _4</ProcessID>
            <CountryCode>CC_NEWZEALAND</CountryCode>
            <AcceptAcknowledge>NE</AcceptAcknowledge>
            <ApplicationAcknowledge>NE</ApplicationAcknowledge>
            <RecevingApplication>KIOSK</RecevingApplication>
            <RecevingFacility>RY7</RecevingFacility>
            <UserID />
        </HeaderDetails>
        <MetaData>
            <BuildNumber>2.666.0.0</BuildNumber>
        </MetaData>
    </CNSDocuments>
    <PatientVisitInformation>
        <PatientVisit>
            <PatientClass>CC_CONT</PatientClass>
            <AssignedPatientLocation>
                <PointOfCare>NSP</PointOfCare>
                <ParentLocation>NSP</ParentLocation>
                <Facility>RY7</Facility>
                <WardName>Not Specified</WardName>
            </AssignedPatientLocation>
            <AdmissionType />
            <EpisodeValue>
                <EpisodeID>2015E0001299</EpisodeID>
                <Facility>RY7</Facility>
            </EpisodeValue>
            <HospitalService />
            <AdmitSource />
            <AmbulatoryService />
            <EncounterValue>
                <EncounterID>2015L0009474</EncounterID>
                <EncounterType>CC_LRCENC</EncounterType>
            </EncounterValue>
            <AdmitDTTM>26/11/2015 10:00:00</AdmitDTTM>
            <DischargeDTTM />
            <ExpectedDischargeDTTM />
            <ReferralSource />
            <PatientType />
            <IsReadmission />
        </PatientVisit>
    </PatientVisitInformation>
    <PatientDemoGraphicDetails>
        <PatientDetails>
            <Sex>CC_Male</Sex>
            <Title>CC_MR</Title>
            <Ethnic />
            <Suffix />
            <Surname>sandy</Surname>
            <Forename>s</Forename>
            <Religion />
            <Deceased>0</Deceased>
            <IsTraced>0</IsTraced>
            <BirthDttm>01/01/0001 00:00:00</BirthDttm>
            <DeathDttm>01/01/0001 00:00:00</DeathDttm>
            <SCNNumber />
            <MiddleName />
            <Nationality />
            <PlaceOfBirth />
            <MultipleBirth />
            <MaritalStatus />
        </PatientDetails>
        <PatientStatus>
            <StatusValueCode />
        </PatientStatus>
        <PatientAddress>
            <Address>
                <CityCode />
                <StateCode />
                <PostalCode />
                <AddressType>CC_USUALADD</AddressType>
                <CountryCode>CC_INDIA_RY1</CountryCode>
                <AddressLine4 />
                <AddressLine3 />
                <AddressLine2 />
                <AddressLine1 />
            </Address>
        </PatientAddress>
        <PatientID>
            <IDType>CC_IDTYTEMPID</IDType>
            <Identifier>T000002406</Identifier>
            <AssigningFacility>RY7</AssigningFacility>
            <AssigningAuthority>RY7</AssigningAuthority>
        </PatientID>
        <OrgROLInfo>
            <OrganisationId>RY7</OrganisationId>
            <OrganisationType>CC_TRUST1</OrganisationType>
            <OrganisationGroup>CC_HEALTH</OrganisationGroup>
            <BusinessAddress>
                <StateCode>MERSEYSIDE</StateCode>
                <PostalCode>CH41 5AL</PostalCode>
                <AddressType>CC_BUSADD</AddressType>
                <CountryCode>CC_UNITEDKINGDOM</CountryCode>
                <AddressLine4>BIRKENHEAD</AddressLine4>
                <AddressLine3 />
                <AddressLine2>HAMILTON STREET</AddressLine2>
                <AddressLine1>OLD MARKET HOUSE</AddressLine1>
            </BusinessAddress>
            <BusinessEmail>
                <ContactType>CC_EMAIL</ContactType>
                <RoleTypeCode>Internet</RoleTypeCode>
                <ContactNumber>rmaniyamghat@csc.com</ContactNumber>
            </BusinessEmail>
            <BusinessContact>
                <ContactType>CC_TELEPHONE</ContactType>
                <RoleTypeCode>Telephone</RoleTypeCode>
                <ContactNumber>0258963147</ContactNumber>
            </BusinessContact>
        </OrgROLInfo>
    </PatientDemoGraphicDetails>
</TRGMDMT02>
```

Comment: Well why are you taking the name? How do you want the values? It's not really clear what you're expecting. You've also posted rather more XML than is really required to demonstrate the problem... ideally, show a short but complete console app which demonstrates what you're trying to achieve, along with a short XML file which is parsed by the app. It doesn't need to have your real data or element names - just enough to show the problem.

Comment: I would suggest you to use Serialization and deserialzation of xml into a class

Comment: @Jon Skeet. I am trying the get value of tag <ActivityDTTM>26/11/2015 05:25:31</ActivityDTTM>

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: XDocument.Load(fileName).Descendants("CNSDocument").Elements().Where(a=>a.Name=="ActivityDTTM").Select(xe => xe.Value);

Answer (score 1):

If there exists exactly on `CNSDocument` in your XML file then you can get the value using this code:

```
var res = xDocument.Descendants("CNSDocument").First().Element("ActivityDTTM").Value;
```

`xDocument.Descendants("CNSDocument")` returns a collection of elements and you have to pick one using `First()` in order to be able to get the elements inside.

Answer (score 0):

```
.Descendants("CNSDocument").Descendants("ActivityDTTM").First().Value
```

Comment: Mind to [explain your solution](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) a bit?